# Phing phpLocTask doesn't work even though PHPLoc is in the include_path

Tags: php, phing

I am converting an Ant `build.xml` into a project using `phing`. One of the targets was using `phploc` which I converted into a target using `<phploc/>` task. I got the error message:

```
Execution of target "phploc" failed for the following reason: \
/Users/david/workspace/phoenix/build-test/build.xml:44:17: \ 
/Users/david/workspace/phoenix/build-test/build.xml:44:17: \
PHPLocTask depends on PHPLoc being installed and on include_path.
```

I downloaded `PHPLoc` which is distributed as a `*.phar` file, and followed the directions in the [README.md](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc/blob/master/README.md).

```
$ phploc -help
phploc 2.0.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage:
  phploc [--names="..."] [--names-exclude="..."] [--count-tests] [--git-repository="..."] [--exclude="..."] [--log-csv="..."] [--log-xml="..."] [--progress] [values1] ... [valuesN]
...
```

I still get the same error message. I found my `include_path`:

```
$ php -i 2> /dev/null | grep "^include_path"
include_path => .:/usr/local/php/includes:/usr/local/pear/share/pear:/usr/lib/php/pear => .:/usr/local/php/includes:/usr/local/pear/share/pear:/usr/lib/php/pear
```

and copied `phploc` to `/usr/local/php/includes`, but I still get the same error message no matter if it's named `PHPLoc` or `phploc`.

I found the phploc task in `/usr/lib/php/pear/phing/Phing/tasks/ext/phploc/PHPLoc.php`:

```
public function main()
{
    /**
     * Find PHPLoc
     */
    if (!class_exists('\SebastianBergmann\PHPLOC\Analyser')) {
        if (!@include_once('SebastianBergmann/PHPLOC/autoload.php')) {
            if (!@include_once('PHPLOC/Analyser.php')) {
                throw new BuildException(
                    'PHPLocTask depends on PHPLoc being installed and on include_path.',
                    $this->getLocation()
                );
            } else {
                $this->oldVersion = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The very first `class_exists` statement isn't returning a *true* value and the `include_once` is not getting the included file. I wonder if this is because phploc is a PHAR package and not individual files.

I can always do an `<exec/>` or `<apply/>` task, but I thought it would be better to use the already defined task.

What do I need to do to *install* phploc, so the `<phploc>` Phing task can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information wasn't on the phploc page, but after going through all the files and a bit of Googling, I found I could do the following:

```
$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.netpirates.net
$ sudo pear install phpunit/phploc
```

This installs phploc via Pear, and Phing is able to use it. Phar packages just don't seem to work with Phing.

Answer (score 4):

PEAR channel is closed now. You should put something like this in Your build.xml:

```
<php expression="include('/var/lib/jenkins/.composer/vendor/autoload.php')"/>
```

and install all dependiens by composer globally as Jenkins user

```
composer global require 'phploc/phploc=*'
```

or include all tools into Your project and set proper autoload file